# Journey Builder - Contact processed twice the amount more than the records in Data Extension

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio

I have a decision split as the first action of a journey, however, I noticed that this step processed/created twice the amount of contacts than what's in the entry source data extension. Could anyone please advise what I could have done wrong here?

Thanks a lot!
Mike

[image]

Comment: Could it be possible that your contacts entered the journey twice? For example, due to `Re-entry anytime` contact entry option?

Comment: and do you have a schedule? also this record count for the de shows the count right now, and not the historic count at time of injection

Comment: Thanks both. I indeed have "re-entry anytime", due to the data extension is overwritten every time the new csv file is imported. I also do have a schedule, then should I be concerned that there'll be duplicates created or it's just a different number (DE count now vs. historic count per injection)?

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comment section, there could be several reasons why 6 contacts entered the journey when you have only 3 records in the Entry Source Data Extension:

- Generally, 6 records could have entered the journey in the past because the Entry Source Data Extension had that 6 records. Now this DE has only 3 records.
- If the number of records in the Data Extension has not changed, then depending on the schedule, those 3 records could have been pushed in the journey twice. Especially when you confirmed that you have the `Re-entry anytime` contact entry option and automated schedule.

Answering your question from the comment -

> I also do have a schedule, then should I be concerned that there'll be duplicates created or it's just a different number (DE count now vs. historic count per injection)?

We do not have any visibility whether you would have duplicates created or not but based on the configuration of the contact entry option, the same contacts might join your journey at any time. In other words, when you import a .csv file in the automation, you push whatever number of contacts you have in the file into the journey, despite whether they are already inside or not.